# SELECT all ORDER BY views and make every 3rd item random

Tags: mysql, sql, database, graphql

```
Products
-- id [int]
-- name [string]
-- views [int]
```

Is it possible to write a query that would return `products` ordered by one or more fields (for example number of views and id) and make every 3rd item totally random?

The general idea is that I have some products:

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id |   name    | views |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | Product 1 |    12 |
|  2 | Product 2 |    65 |
|  3 | Product 3 |    23 |
|  4 | Product 4 |    23 |
|  5 | Product 5 |    32 |
|  6 | Product 6 |    76 |
|  7 | Product 7 |    35 |
|  8 | Product 8 |    91 |
|  9 | Product 9 |    73 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

And I want to show the most popular products so I want to order them by views. However, products that are not popular will not be able to compete with other products if they will not get enough traction. It would be nice if I could occasionally show even the unpopular products among the popular products so that they could become popular too.

**Database:** I will use graphql and mysql but any solution will be helpful

**Total items:** Thousands

**Pagination:** 9 - 18 per page

**Important thing is that I have to create the database structure only once. Any other column (property) that would help with the ordering can be set up. Only number of `views` will change over time.**

Comment: Wouldn't making every 3rd item random defeat the purpose of ORDER BY?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean to make every 3rd item totally random? You want to order by 1 or 2 fields that is possible but then you want randomness?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I will edit the question in a minte. The general idea is that I want to display some items by their popularity. But I also want to display some items randomly so that even those items that are not popular are sometimes visible.

Comment: Good question :) I just edited my question. Total items per page maybe 9 - 18. But in a database there might be thousands of items in total.

Comment: I suppose you could set a temp table to hold your top x records ordered by views, then have a second table holding your bottom x records, then insert 2 from top x into 3rd temp table and 1 from bottom x then delete those records from temp tables 1 and 2 until you remove all records from temps 1 and 2? There is probably some complicated set based way but It's been a long week and that was the best my tired brain could muster.

Comment: That is actually a really good idea. However, I don't think I will have that much power over the database. I will use scaphold or graphcool as a serverless backend. And graphql to query the data. I was thinking more something like creating another item property (column) with some random value that would change the order of the items? Or create property (column) that would just has something like `order_string` in it.

Comment: Which ones would be part of the "Random" pool though. You wouldn't want to accidently make one of your high view items get randomly distributed in of the `row_number() mod 3` group. I think this really needs to be broken down logically before anyone can offer up code to help. As @GordonLinoff suggested, please provide desired results for some sample data. That might better help explain what are you thinking through besides "every 3rd one is random".. random from what pool? How is that pool determined?

Comment: Important thing is that I have to create the database structure only once. Any other column (property) that would help with the ordering can be set up. Only the number of views will change over time.

Comment: Are you looking for a GraphQL solution or a SQL solution?

Comment: Ideally graphql but I know that there are far more SQL experts who will be able to show me at least a direction I should take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this request is hideous, but it should give you what you expect

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/864b7b/17)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM T 
    ORDER BY `VIEWS` DESC 
    LIMIT 2
    ) A

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM T T0
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM (
            SELECT ID 
            FROM T 
            ORDER BY `VIEWS` DESC 
            LIMIT 2
            ) T1
        WHERE T1.ID = T0.ID
        )
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
    ) B
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/864b7b/17/0)**:

```
| id |      name | views |
|----|-----------|-------|
|  8 | Product 8 |    91 |
|  6 | Product 6 |    76 |
|  3 | Product 3 |    23 |
```

Comment: This is awesome. :)

Comment: @Michal you're welcome, and good luck to make this with GraphQL XD

Comment: @Michal . . . This query returns three rows.  Hence it doesn't seem to answer your question.  I'm surprised you accepted the answer.